# Training accuracy improving but validation accuracy remain at 0.5, and model predicts nearly the same class for every validation sample

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am implementing a ResNet50 + LSTM and attention model using keras tensorflow backend on a dataset of time lapsed IVF embryos images.

The dataset consist of about 220 samples and I am using a 85% - 15% train/validation split (203 on training and 27 on validation).

My model was able to achieve a training accuracy of 0.80+ but the validation accuracy is either stuck around 0.5 or just stays at 0.5, and the validation loss is nearly twice of training loss.

Is this only an over-fitting problem?

If not, how could I debug and improve the performance on validation set?

#Things I tried:

I tried to add regularization(L1, 0.01)/Dropout layers(0.5)/reducing the neuron(1024 to 512 to 256) but none of them works)

I also normalized my data through subtracting the mean and dividing the standard deviation.

I am using an Adam optimizer with 1e-5 learning rate without weight decay. The images are shuffled before training.

#Below are the code for my model and the progress bar

#Progress Bar:

```
Epoch 1/40

150/150 [==============================] - 28s 189ms/step - loss: 2.1318 - acc: 0.5267 - val_loss: 4.8806 - val_acc: 0.5556



Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 4.88055, saving model to result/resnetmodel.hdf5

Epoch 2/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 94ms/step - loss: 1.9957 - acc: 0.5867 - val_loss: 4.8210 - val_acc: 0.5000



Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 4.88055 to 4.82100, saving model to result/resnetmodel.hdf5

Epoch 3/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 94ms/step - loss: 1.8062 - acc: 0.6200 - val_loss: 4.9689 - val_acc: 0.5000



Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 4/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 91ms/step - loss: 1.7516 - acc: 0.6267 - val_loss: 5.0284 - val_acc: 0.5000



Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 5/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 94ms/step - loss: 1.6508 - acc: 0.7000 - val_loss: 4.9873 - val_acc: 0.4444



Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 6/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 92ms/step - loss: 1.5003 - acc: 0.7733 - val_loss: 4.9800 - val_acc: 0.4444



Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 7/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 96ms/step - loss: 1.4614 - acc: 0.7667 - val_loss: 4.9435 - val_acc: 0.5000



Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 8/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 90ms/step - loss: 1.5480 - acc: 0.6800 - val_loss: 4.9345 - val_acc: 0.5000



Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 9/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 93ms/step - loss: 1.4334 - acc: 0.7667 - val_loss: 5.0452 - val_acc: 0.5000



Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 10/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 94ms/step - loss: 1.4344 - acc: 0.7667 - val_loss: 5.1768 - val_acc: 0.4444



Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 11/40

150/150 [==============================] - 15s 98ms/step - loss: 1.3369 - acc: 0.8533 - val_loss: 5.1331 - val_acc: 0.4444



Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 12/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 93ms/step - loss: 1.2834 - acc: 0.8133 - val_loss: 5.1265 - val_acc: 0.4444



Epoch 00012: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 13/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 91ms/step - loss: 1.3007 - acc: 0.8200 - val_loss: 5.1941 - val_acc: 0.4444



Epoch 00013: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 14/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 94ms/step - loss: 1.2358 - acc: 0.8533 - val_loss: 5.3716 - val_acc: 0.4444



Epoch 00014: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 15/40

150/150 [==============================] - 14s 92ms/step - loss: 1.2823 - acc: 0.8000 - val_loss: 5.3877 - val_acc: 0.4444
```

Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 4.82100

Epoch 00015: early stopping

Evaluation: ----load data

----prediction_on_eval-----

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[0.03809702 0.96190304]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[0.9803326 0.0196674]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[9.9986279e-01 1.3717638e-04]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[0.98158103 0.01841903]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[0.99492776 0.00507224]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[0.70435154 0.29564843]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[4.1277369e-04 9.9958724e-01]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[0.9818978  0.01810225]

fact=[1. 0.], Predicted=[0.91195923 0.08804072]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.986312 0.013688]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.9985434  0.00145668]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.80424094 0.195759  ]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.9214819  0.07851809]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.03754392 0.96245605]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[9.9976009e-01 2.3989924e-04]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.98681134 0.01318868]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.9984666 0.0015334]

fact=[0. 1.], Predicted=[0.7229417  0.27705824]

#Here is my model:

```py
x =Input(shape = (40, config.img_shape, config.img_shape, config.img_channel))

if config.base_model == "inception_v3":

    cnn = InceptionV3(weights = None, include_top=False, pooling = "avg")

elif config.base_model == 'ResNet50':

    cnn = ResNet50(weights = None, include_top=False, pooling = "avg")
    
cnn.load_weights(config.pretrained_path)

for layer in cnn.layers:

    layer.trainable = False


extracted_features = TimeDistributed(cnn)(x)

activations = Bidirectional(LSTM(config.num_units_lstm, return_sequences=True,                              recurrent_activation = 'relu', recurrent_initializer = 'glorot_uniform', name='Bidirectional_LSTM'))(extracted_features)

activations = Dropout(0.5)(activations)

attention = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='tanh'),name = "context_vector")(activations)

attention = Flatten()(attention)

attention = Activation('softmax', name = "conext_weights")(attention)

attention = RepeatVector(config.num_units_lstm*2)(attention)

attention = Permute([2, 1])(attention)

sent_representation = merge.multiply([activations, attention])

sent_representation = Lambda(lambda xin: K.sum(xin, axis=1))(sent_representation)

sent_representation = BatchNormalization()(sent_representation)

prediction = Dense(config.num_classes, activation = 'softmax')(sent_representation)

model =  Model(inputs = x, outputs = prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The dataset consist of about 220 samples and I am using a 85% - 15% train/validation split (203 on training and 27 on validation).
>
> Is this only an over-fitting problem?

It sounds very likely, yes. 220 samples is very very small dataset for such a deep network. It's really unlikely to be able to learn to generalise well from such a small set of data.

> If not, how could I debug and improve the performance on validation set?

In an ideal world, grab another 100,000 or so samples and add them to your dataset!

Accepting this is probably impractical you could try one or a combination of these strategies:

- use [image augmentation](https://medium.com/@thimblot/data-augmentation-boost-your-image-dataset-with-few-lines-of-python-155c2dc1baec) to artificially increase the size of your dataset
- Instead of trying to train a deep network from scratch. Investigate using tensorflow_hub in order to just train the last layer (and or fine tune) an pre-trained network ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining)).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues:

- used  `ImageDataGenerator from keras.preprocessing.image` to  to perform image augmentation on the fly
- used Transfer Learning, VGG16 and MobileNetV2 etc. with pre-trained weights

Still I was getting 0.5 val_loss.
This solved my situation, I hope it helps you:

Replacing `model =  Model(inputs = x, outputs = prediction)`
with 
 `model = Model(inputs = x.inputs, outputs = prediction)`